# Play Framework (Java) - Caching results from an action based on parameters

Tags: caching, playframework

We can cache the results in play framework from an action using

```
@Cached(key = "homePage")
public static Result index() {
    return ok("Hello world");
}
```

Is there a way where we can cache the result based on the input parameters (GET request) like id in this particular case .. which can be for example a user_id

```
@Cached(key = "cachedData")
public static Result getCacheData(long id) {
    //return a dummy data on some manner
    String cachedData = "Hello world" + id;
    return ok(cachedData);
}
```